# What web framework is used by Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I want to create web product, that can have the same rich ajax features that Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 has. Does Microsoft has such SDK?

I think it may be Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010, but it is targeted to small organization's Intranet, but not world wide Internet.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attended a Microsoft Dynamics Technical conference in 2009, at the conference we were told MS Dynamics is based on a UI Framework that takes its core from the same foundation as the ASP.Net core of the .Net framework. Microsoft offer an [MS Dynamics specific SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/bb467596) if you are looking at customising an instance of Dynamics CRM.

To get the same, or very similar, functionality I would look at ASP.Net (Ajax based) UI Controls from 3rd party vendors such as [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) and [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is a big supporter of jQuery.

I've not got access to my test CRM 2011 system from here at work, but I don't think they use it in CRM 2011.  Their Javascript is probably all custom, as they'd probably face possible future licencing and legal issues on a big flagship product if they included any 3rd party Javascript library.

jQuery will provide you with tabs, accordions, hover overs and has plugins for just about anything else including things in CRM 2011 like context menus, form validation and light-weight grids.

Answer (score 1):

You could to take a look at Telerik [RibbonBar](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ribbonbar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) and [PanelBar](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx). Many other controls as [TreeList](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) and [Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) are also available.

BTW, while Sharepoint Foundation 2010 isn't targeted for internet use, you can rely on Sharepoint Server 2010 for some scenarios. But, first, take a look on [licencing prices](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010-price-calculator/default.aspx)

Comment: Telerik looks very close. But for example on Web Mail Demo http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/webmail/ clicking on Panel (in left bottom coner) will cause page load, while in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online it is like desktop Outlook.

Comment: You always can use an UpdatePanel/AJAX

Answer (score 0):

A good way to have rich ajax features is [ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) by Sencha.